# VB.NET UpdateResource is always capital and adds resource, not update

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, resources, native

I am wondering why my updateresource is not working. It is always capital, and does not update/replace the resource, only adds one.

Here is my code in VB.NET

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Dim strMiniConfig As String
    strMiniConfig = TextBox1.Text

    Dim encoder As New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding()

    WriteResource("UpdateMyRes.exe", encoder.GetBytes(strMiniConfig))

    MsgBox("Resources are now updated.", vbOKOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Information)

End Sub


<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Private Shared Function UpdateResource(ByVal hUpdate As IntPtr, ByVal lpType As String, ByVal lpName As String, ByVal wLanguage As UShort, ByVal lpData As IntPtr, ByVal cbData As UInteger) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Private Shared Function BeginUpdateResource(ByVal pFileName As String, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal bDeleteExistingResources As Boolean) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
Private Shared Function EndUpdateResource(ByVal hUpdate As IntPtr, ByVal fDiscard As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function

Public Function WriteResource(ByVal filename As String, ByVal bytes As Byte()) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim handle As IntPtr = BeginUpdateResource(filename, False)
        Dim file1 As Byte() = bytes
        Dim fileptr As IntPtr = ToPtr(file1)
        Dim res As Boolean = UpdateResource(handle, "RCData", "CONFIG", 1, fileptr, System.Convert.ToUInt16(file1.Length))
        EndUpdateResource(handle, False)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True

End Function

Private Function ToPtr(ByVal data As Object) As IntPtr
    Dim h As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    Dim ptr As IntPtr
    Try
        ptr = h.AddrOfPinnedObject()
    Finally
        h.Free()
    End Try
    Return ptr

End Function
End Class
```

This should replace a resource from RCData\CONFIG but it always adds resource with name RCDATA\CONFIG ? Why is that?

Here is the same code in C++:

```cpp
WCHAR * newD = L"I am updated resource at the RCData\CONFIG";
HANDLE hUpdate = BeginUpdateResourceW(L"Stub.exe", false);
UpdateResourceW(hUpdate, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(10), L"CONFIG", 1, newD, wcslen(newD)*2);
EndUpdateResource(hUpdate, false);
```

Comment: Note how in the C++ code the resource type is not the string "RCDATA", but a numeric value `MAKEINTRESOURCEW(10)` (also known as `RT_RCDATA`). These are entirely different things. That's why your VB code always creates a new resource; roughly speaking, it puts it into a wrong "folder". Before you ask, I don't know VB well enough to help you fix your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed now by using different API.

Will close this when I can.